# XJC NullPointerException only in Java > 7u40

Tags: java, jaxb, java-7, xjc

I run the following command

`exec /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java  -jar jaxb-xjc.jar TestPolicy.xsd`

and the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:776)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setProperty(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:448)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.setProperty(SchemaParsingConfig.java:492)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.setProperty(SchemaDOMParser.java:503)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reset(XSDHandler.java:3594)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1068)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:561)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLGrammarPreparser.preparseGrammar(XMLGrammarPreparser.java:205)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:78)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.loadXMLSchema(GrammarLoader.java:330)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:127)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:76)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:181)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:80)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:46)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:60)
```

If I run the same command using jdk1.7.0_25, I don't get the exception and everything runs succesfully.

Any idea what the difference is between the 1.7 update 25 and the 1.7 update 40 or update 45 version?

Note: I found the following two links that seem similar. One is a bug for openjdk but there doesn't seem to be a bug entered at java sun website. 
[OpenJDK Bug Ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029837?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel)
and 
[ESPER Error](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ESPER-764)

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround that is "good enough" for me and I need jaxb1 so replacing xjc was not possible

From the GrammarLoader source:

```
        if(opt.strictCheck && !SchemaConstraintChecker.check(opt.getGrammars(), errorReceiver, opt.entityResolver))
```

From Options.java source:

```
       if(args[i].equals("-nv"))
    {
        strictCheck = false;
        return 1;
    }
```

From the command line parameter documentation

```
    -nv                :  do not perform strict validation of the input schema(s)
```

=> using

```
<xjc .../>
  <arg value="-nv" />
</xjc>
```

disables the SchemaConstraintChecker.check(...) that results in the NPE

Comment: is this advisable to remove SchemaConstraintChecker.check() ?

Comment: I guess it depends on your project. In my case I get schemas from another project and I can rely that they are valid.
Maybe if you disable the strict checking in xjc/jaxb1 you can put some manual checks from another tool.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: I had similar issue (i.e. giving NPE) but calling it from ant task. Instead of using a separate jaxb-xjc.jar (from http://jaxb.java.net), I decided to use the included xjc.exe that comes with the JDK 1.7 (under bin) and works like a charm.

in windows:

%JAVA_HOME%/bin/xjc.exe /?

If for some reasons, you have to use the library, make sure you get the latest (2.2.7 as of this writing) to be used with jdk 1.7

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that does help but it seems like the xjc from the newer libraries react differently with my xsd than the old xjc. So this is still an issue for me.